как спарсить <tr class?
Необходимо спарсить <td class = "text-center set-td">
код простецкий у меня, как у безопытного
import requests

url = 'https://tennis-score.pro/games/vardges-saroyan-narek-dekermendzhyan-2689639/'
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()
print(response.text)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
title_tag = soup.find('tbody') **#если добавляю .find('') - чтобы в ковычках не вписал, дает ошибку. если оставляю так, то выдает всю инфу, даты/время.** 
title_text = title_tag.text
print(title_text)

Нужны только числа, хранящиеся в :
td class="text-center set-td">11</td>
td class="text-center set-td">4</td>


print(*(x.text for x in soup('td')[2:4]))

Можно просто найти все теги с классом text-center set-td, а затем выбрать какие-то необходимые данные.
Cначала находим всю таблицу:
table = soup.find("tbody")

Затем находим все теги с соответствующим классом:
tags = table.find_all(class_="text-center set-td")

И в конце можем уже извлечь текст из тегов и как-то обработать эти данные. Перебрать список с тегами можно через списковое включение:
values = [tag.text for tag in tags]

Или, к примеру, привести к удобному виду
values = []
for i in range(0, len(tags), 6):
    values.append([tag.text for tag in tags[i:i + 6]])

[['11', '6', '11', '8', '11', '9'],
 ['11', '9', '11', '7', '11', '3'],
 ['11', '7', '11', '6', '11', '4'],
 ['11', '4', '11', '8', '11', '8'],
 ['11', '7', '12', '10', '11', '4'],
 ['11', '9', '11', '5', '11', '5'],
 ['11', '5', '11', '5', '12', '10'],
 ['11', '7', '11', '6', '11', '8'],
 ['11', '4', '11', '3', '11', '9'],
 ['11', '2', '11', '5', '11', '5']]

